# Run my application on my client's simulator

Tags: macos, iphone

My client want to run  my application on his system (simulator) but he does not have IphoneSDK   but have a mac
Also he is not registered with apple
What to do

Comment: Does the client have an actual iPhone/iPod/iPod device?

Comment: Yes but i am not registered with apple to make an adhoc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tell him that he needs a free Apple account to download the SDK and the simulator. There is no way around this and as he has already a Mac, it shouldn't be that complicated for him.

Also: If he has a newer Mac OS X DVD, the developer tools are already on it. But I'm not really sure if the iPhone SDK and the simulator also ship with it, but if he has a slow internet connection, he should give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to have developer profile to download current iOS SDK so your client can easily do that and install it on his mac.

After that all you need is to build a binary for iPhone simulator target and send it to client. To install application on simulator you need to copy your application binary to arbitrary folder in simulator's applications folder (path to it on my mac is /Users/Vladimir/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/123/)